# how to get query criteria in access vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Now I am trying to create customize query design view form with Access VBA. I want to show fields name and criteria of saved query.

For example, SQL statement that executed by **QueryDef.sql is**

```
SELECT AllCars.ID, AllCars.CarName
FROM AllCars
WHERE (((AllCars.ID) Between 15 And 25) AND ((AllCars.MinPay)<1000)) ;
```

I would like to get criteria expressions( ID = Between 15 And 25, MinPay =  <1000) and field names(ID , CarName) from it.
I can get field name but I am not sure how to get query criteria expression in Access VBA.
I tried to split sql statement but I think this is not a best way for multiple criteria expressions.
If getting criteria in access vba may be possible, could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to implement an Access SQL parser to do this reliably. That's an extremely challenging task.

Comment: This is a dead end. You must rethink your concept.

Comment: I have done something like this on a limited scale. Takes a bunch of code. When you have some with issue, post question. A search form to dynamically build filter criteria is a common topic.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code that creates the saved query: instead of saving all the SQL together, save the field names separately and the expressions separately.

To keep all the fields together but in a way that you can later separate them, put the character ";" between the field names, and to separate them you will use the `split` function.

You can do the same for the expressions, and when you read the saved data you associate the position in the array of the expression with the position of the field in the array and thus you connect them together to show the user which expression applies to which field.

In the same way you build the query